# Max-Age cookie value using Spring ResponseCookie

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

when creating a cookie with

```
@GetMapping("getCookieUsingResponseCookie")
  public ResponseEntity<?> getCookieUsingResponseCookie() {
   Duration d = Duration.ofDays(7);
    ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY","123-LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY-VALUE-456")
      .domain("localhost")
      .httpOnly(true)
//      .maxAge(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) // a week
      .maxAge(d)
//      .maxAge(500) // a week
      .path("/")
      .secure(true)
      .build();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString());    
    System.out.println(cookie.toString());    
   ResponseEntity<?> response = new ResponseEntity<>(null, headers, HttpStatus.OK);  
   return response;
  }
```

or even if I use

```
.maxAge(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) // a week
```

instead of a duration the cookie looks like:

```
Set-Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=123-LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY-VALUE-456; Path=/; Domain=localhost; Max-Age=PT168H; Expires=Tue, 14 Jun 2022 22:35:02 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
```

the Max-Age=PT168H seems wrong compared to other cookies or using javax.servlet.http.Cookie

Looked in the RFC but did not see anything about that format. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M4_to_5.0.0.M5/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.M5/org/springframework/http/ResponseCookie.html#maxAge) **maxAge** attribute is type `java.time.Duration`.
So, what you see is `toString()` representation of Duration object.

Duration `toString()` returns a string representation of duration using ISO-8601 seconds based representation, such as `PT8H6M12.345S`.

The format of the string will be `PTnHnMnS`, where `n` is the relevant hours, minutes or seconds part of the duration.

**Examples:**

```
"20.345 seconds"                 -- "PT20.345S
"15 minutes" (15 * 60 seconds)   -- "PT15M"
"10 hours" (10 * 3600 seconds)   -- "PT10H"
"2 days" (2 * 86400 seconds)     -- "PT48H"
```

So 7 days will have 7*24 hours which is 168 hours in total, which will be described using above schema as : **PT168H**